# Large Curly brackets

Tags: symbols, delimiters

So I'm new to `LaTeX` and I have a problem. I want to type large curly brackets. My document type is `article`
To be more specific, here's what I want to type:[image]

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with `\left\{` and `\right\}`?

Comment: Are you sure you should have *two* closing braces at the end?

Comment: Oh yeah I got it thank you all!!

Comment: @Bernard I didn't get it! Why you think he shouldn't?

Comment: @Tarek Acila you have two answers now, if you think any of them works for you, you'd better click accept (tick) left side the answer box. You may also vote up either or both if it's ok with you.

Comment: @hesham oh yeah ofc, it,s done. I'm new here so I did not know I should click accept, sorry. Thank you.

Comment: @Tarek Acila Welcome to our community.

Comment: @hesham: the inner braces do not denote a set, but a series of three conditions, so the inner left brace is enough (just like in the `cases` environment).

Comment: @Bernard, Mico, Schrödinger's cat, I think he's trying to accept all the answers. Luck going for the last one :)

Comment: @Bernard Well, the single or double braces could be used interchangeably though, informally speaking.

Comment: @hesham Hhh don't worry I realized that moments ago. I have fixed it I accepted the very first answer.

Comment: @Bernard You could have better noted the extra division operator after the \Re set in the array group! I think it's "such that" or colon symbol.

Comment: Yes, but it is not used in the context of a new set.. Please take a look at mu=y updated answer: I've added what I have in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this go in the right direction?

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[\tau=\left\{ G\subset\overline{\mathfrak{R}}/ \forall x\in G,
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{\ /\ }l@{,\ }l@{}}
\exists a,b\in\mathfrak{R} & x\in [a,b\mathclose[\subset G&x\ne\pm\infty\\
\exists b\in\mathfrak{R} & x\in [-\infty,b[\subset G&x=-\infty\\
\exists a\in\mathfrak{R} & x\in \mathopen]a,\infty]\subset G&x=+\infty
\end{array}\right\}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I am not sure I understand the notation, though.) **EDIT**: Added `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`, as suggested by @egreg.)

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly fine.

Comment: `x\in[-\infty,b\mathclose[` or the spacing goes awry. Similarly, in the third line, `x\in\mathopen]a,+\infty]` (the OP uses `+\infty`, but the main thing is `\mathopen`). The first line should have `x\in\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[`

Comment: @egreg Mille grazie! I agree, of course. (I must admit that I do not fully grasp the meaning of `/\forall\in G` and the full construction. If  it is what I think it could be I'd probably typeset it in a different way.)

Comment: That's not the best way to describe the standard topology on the extended real line. Too many symbols make it very difficult to understand. By the way, looking at the OP's picture, the top line should be `x\in\mathopen]a,b\mathclose[`

Answer (score 5):

Yet another solution, in two variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set} \{ \}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

   \[ 
   \tau = \set*{%
   G \subset \widebar{\Re}\bigm / \forall X\in G, \begin{Bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{@{}l!{/}l@{\:}l@{}}
     \exists a, b \in\Re & x\in{]a, b[}\subset G, &x\ne \pm\infty \\
     \exists b \in\Re & x\in{[-\infty, b[}\subset G, &x = -\infty \\
     \exists ab \in\Re & x\in {]a, + \infty]} \subset G, &x = + \infty
    \end{array}
   \end{Bmatrix}}%
   \]%

   \[
   \tau = \set*{%
   G \subset \widebar{\Re}\bigm / \forall X\in G, \begin{cases}
    \begin{array}{@{}l!{/}l@{\:}l@{}}
     \exists a, b \in\Re & x\in{]a, b[}\subset G, &x\ne \pm\infty \\
     \exists b \in\Re & x\in{[-\infty, b[}\subset G, &x = -\infty \\
     \exists ab \in\Re & x\in {]a, + \infty]} \subset G, &x = + \infty
    \end{array}
   \end{cases}}%
   \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Or maybe something like this? (Note that I've gone ahead and inserted commas as separators in the interval expressions.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for "\mathfrak" macro
\newcommand\R{\mathfrak{R}}

\begin{document}
\[
\tau=
\left\{
G\subset\overline{\R} \mid \forall x\in G,
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
\exists a,b\in\R \mid 
   x\in\mathopen{]}a,b\mathclose{[} \subset G,\ x\ne\pm\infty \\
\exists b\in\R \mid
   [-\infty,b\mathclose{[} \subset G,\ x=-\infty \\
\exists a\in\R \mid
   \mathopen{]}a,+\infty]  \subset G,\ x=+\infty
\end{array}
\right\}
\right\}     
\]
\end{document}
```